# Codeigniter caching question

Tags: php, caching, codeigniter

I’m fairly new to Codeigniter. I have been reading the user guide extensively but one question has remained open for me.

Consider this scenario:

*An article page, completely static with only one little dynamic text displaying the number of views this article has got.*

How could I cache such a page in order to serve it fast but still update the views counter?

Any answer will be greatly appreciated,

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure CI's caching out of the box is for full pages only, so your views count would not be updated.

You could either specify a large cache time e.g. `$this->output->cache(180);` which would cache for 2 hours, and then update the count, or look in to partial caching. Here's [one such library](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/69843/).

Comment: is there a way to split a view into fragments and cache fragments of it?

Comment: You can fragment your views all you want since CodeIgniter joins all the views you call, but CI's built-in caching system will still cache the entire rendered page as-is.